# Importing librosa package with AWS lambda throws OSError('sndfile library not found')

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to run Librosa package in the AWS lambda function. Now the package library size along with dependencies is much bigger to use lambda layers or the .zip file using S3. Hence I'm using the option of mounting an EFS file system onto the lambda function. I've followed this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FA153BGOV_A&t=323s) and could install numpy and test that the mounting path works with lambda. I am using an Amazon Linux 2 AMI for my Ec2 instance.

Here is the error I have observed when importing librosa to the lambda library. [image]
It throws me an error with sndfile library not found in soundfile.py

My EFS file mount absolute path in EC2 is /home/ec2-user/mountpoint/pylib where all my python library files are installed using
`pip install --upgrade --target pylib/ <library-name>`

Following the steps here I've installed the sndfile library also in pylib as

```
./configure --prefix=/home/ec2-user/mountpoint/pylib/sndfile --disable-static && make 
make install

The output of make install is 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /home/ec2-user/mountpoint/pylib/sndfile/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/home/ec2-user/mountpoint/pylib/sndfile/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sndfile.hh '/home/ec2-user/mountpoint/pylib/sndfile/include'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/home/ec2-user/mountpoint/pylib/sndfile/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sndfile.h '/home/ec2-user/mountpoint/pylib/sndfile/include'
```

The soundfile.py uses ctypes.util.find_library function to locate sndfile. I am unsure of how to resolve this issue now. What is the path the soundfile.py searching for sndfile library?
Would really appreciate if anyone can give me a clue on this.

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out eventually?

Answer (score 0):

This is may be a bit late, but I've found myself in the exact same position. What seemed to work for me was to downgrade the lambda runtime to python 3.7. I still had to compile the libsndfile from source, but everything seems to be running now using EFS.

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding compiling libsndfile and where do you put it in your project? thank you

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, I created a small [repo](https://github.com/kingsleyzissou/lambda-libsndfile) for it (using the serverless framework).


But essentially, I just added an AWS Lambda layer. I never looked into it, but AWS Lambda now supports [container images](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/) now, that could be a solution too

Comment: oh, I have got that github repo from medium. I guess you are the author. https://gianlucazuccarelli.medium.com/librosa-and-aws-lambda-20e48f23b57e 
you put Librosa in the EFS, right? in my case, I am using SoundFile and it can fit in lambda. I deployed the layer using aws SAM framework. This is my libsndfile layer repo https://github.com/Jun711/libsndfile-aws-lambda-layer

Comment: if you still have the lambda set up, do you mind trying install soundfile in your lambda that has that libsnd layer using `pip install soundfile`, import soundfile and see if throws this sndfile library not found error?
I am thinking to try app-runner / container images if this doesn't work.